# HTML include menu - current page css

Tags: html, css, include

I have to include an HTML menu. 
I need to edit the active page from the css menu.

include menu:

```
<div w3-include-html="inc/header.html"></div>
```

```css
/*CSS example - but not working:*/

.main-menu a.active {
  color: #0061bb;
}
```

```html
<div class="mnmenu-sec">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12 nav-menu">
        <div class="col-md-3">
          <div class="logo">
            <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt="" /></a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-9">
          <div class="menu">
            <nav id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
              <ul>
                <li><a href="index.html">menu 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="page2.html">menu 2</a></li>
              </ul>
            </nav>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I need to highlight an active page from the menu, such as changing the font color.
Can you tell me how I could do it?

Comment: Your pseudo class has a wrong syntax, you should use 'a:active'.
All pseudo classes are preceded by a colon. Also active works after its selected. use hover to change the color on hovering

Answer (score 0):

:active = when a link it is being clicked.
:hover = when the mouse cursor is over the link

If you want the :active then this css should do it:

```
    #main-menu a:active {
      color: #0061bb;
    }
```

If you wanna color the link you currently are, than you need JavaScript to add a class like class="currentLink" then add css to it

```
    .currentLink {
      color: #0061bb;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```css
.main-menu a {
    color: #000;
    transition: 0.3s;
}

.main-menu a:hover {
    color: #0061bb;
}
```

```html
<div class="mnmenu-sec">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12 nav-menu">
                <div class="col-md-3">
                    <div class="logo">
                        <a href="index.html"><img src="img/logo.png" alt=""/></a>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="menu">
                        <nav id="main-menu" class="main-menu">
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="index.html">menu 1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="page2.html">menu 2</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </nav>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```